# Push Navigation Controller into Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift4

I have a ViewController which consists of screens built programatically.Lets say FirstVc.
On Button click I want on window, Navigation Controller From my Storyboard 
[(As Seen in the Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Dwq.png)

As seen in picture, I have my SecondViewController embedded in a navigation controller

With my current code in an OnButtonClick func. It throws the error can’t push navigation controller insider navigation controller.
Which is true. But if I Only Instantiate ViewController from my Main.storyboard, I will not be able to see the top nav bar.

Also , I do not want to use  .present as I want the entire window to change.
Square braces representing storyboard.

FirstVc <---> [Navigatiob->Tab->SecondVC]

***What are possible ways to achieve link represented by dotted lines ?***

Scene Delegate

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
            guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
//            
                    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
                    window?.windowScene = windowScene

                    let navigation = AppNavigationView()

                    let viewController  = ViewController()

    navigation.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                    window?.rootViewController = navigation
                    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Function in ViewController

```
    @objc func buttonTapped(){

        let viewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navC") as! UINavigationController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        self.present(viewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

        print("button tapped")
    }
```

*Error log*

--Moved to active state ---
2020-04-02 20:49:43.978018+0530 Snug[13340:370457] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: What about retrieving the first UIViewController of the UINavigationController of the Main.Storyboard instead and push it?

Comment: Yes That would be about it, I do not know how id do it

Comment: Hi, I have tried to convey my problem clearly in the edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are instantiating a navigation controller from your storyboard. Get the top view controller.

```
@objc func buttonTapped(){

    let viewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navC") as! UINavigationController
    if let top = viewController.topViewController {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(top, animated: true)
    }

    print("button tapped")
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for writing in,
I do not want to use present.. is there any other way?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to get rid of that line. I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Hi, Since I thought I wasnt clear enough, I have tried to convey my problem clearly in the edit now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of items that seem to be wrong here. You are not setting the `ViewController` as `rootViewController` of `NavigationController`. And you are trying to push a new ViewController which is another NavigationController. Here is what you need.

First: UISceneDelegate.swift

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Second: ViewController.swift

```
@objc func navigate() {
    tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Note: SecondViewController is of type UIViewController and not UINaviationViewController.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for writing in, I did try this, I am getting the same error as I have updated in the edit –

Comment: @SameehAhmed Did you add the image just now? I got the issue your view controller is embedded inside a tabbarcontroller which in turn is embedded inside a navigationController.

Comment: No I did not add the image just now, can you help me out though? Yes That is correct. I have a tabC embeded in a navigation C

Comment: @SameehAhmed check the `navigate` function now it should work for you.

Comment: You need to embed your view controller inside your navigation controller which should be embedded inside the tab bar controller.

Comment: 1.embeded view controller inside your navigation controller which should be embedded inside the tab bar controller.
2. changed function in ViewController and Nothing happened. No change at all

Comment: I changed my code so that it would work for you as it is. You don't have to do step 1.

Comment: I've created a repo to help you check this link https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/NavigationTest.

Comment: Hi, Since I thought I wasnt clear enough, I have tried to convey my problem clearly in the edit now.

Answer (score 0):

In function navigate first set the second controller with a let constant, after that call it in pushViewController:

```
@objc func navigate() {
 let secondController = SecondViewController() 
 navigationController?.pushViewController(secondController, animated: true)
}
```

naturally set scene delegate like this

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let vC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    window?.rootViewController = vC
}
```

Comment: Hi, Since I thought I wasnt clear enough, I have tried to convey my problem clearly in the edit now.

Comment: Hi, your code i very confused, When the app start, what controller do you want to see? The ViewController? after that you want to navigate in second controller with pushViewController, is it right?

Comment: yes, When when the app starts I want to see ViewController